# Help on Self-Referential CTE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, cte, recursive, self-join

I have this table below which is has a hierarchy to it where the number of levels vary, for this example I chose a subset with 7 levels.

```
L_Key   Parent  Level P_Key
-------------------------
1393    NULL    0     2
1399    1393    1     325
4485    1399    2     NULL
4505    4485    3     NULL
5066    4505    4     NULL
6121    5066    5     NULL
5068    6121    6     NULL
```

My goal is to grab the property of the Parent that isn't NULL. So in this case, this should be returned:

```
L_Key   Parent  Level P_Key
-------------------------
1393    NULL    0     2
1399    1393    1     325
4485    1399    2     325
4505    4485    3     325
5066    4505    4     325
6121    5066    5     325
5068    6121    6     325
```

This is what i have tried so far.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        m.Functional_Location_Key           
        ,m.Parent_Key
        ,m.Level
        ,m.Property_Key
    FROM #MappingPartOne m
    WHERE m.Functional_Location_Key IN (6121,5068,5066,4505,4485,1399,1393)

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        t.Functional_Location_Key           
        ,t.Parent_Key
        ,t.Level
        ,t.Property_Key
    FROM CTE t
    JOIN #MappingPartOne b ON b.Parent_Key = t.Functional_Location_Key
)
SELECT  
    Functional_Location_Key         
    ,Parent_Key
    ,Level
    ,Property_Key
FROM CTE
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Except this causes an infinite loop.

Thank you for your help.

I have setup a table variable for your testing

```
DECLARE @MappingPartOne TABLE (
    Functional_Location_Key int,
    Parent_Key int,
    Level int,
    Property_Key int
)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (1393,   NULL,   0,  2)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (1399,   1393,   1,  325)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (4485,   1399,   2,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (4505,   4485,   3,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (5066,   4505,   4,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (6121,   5066,   5,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @MappingPartOne VALUES (5068,   6121,   6,  NULL)
```

Comment: Clarification: Do you mean that, when a given row's `Property_Key` is `NULL`, it should use the `Property_Key` of its *nearest ancestor* with a non-`NULL` `Property_Key`? Or, that it should use the `Property_Key` of the *earliest ancestor* with a non-`NULL` `Property_Key`? For example: If the row with the ID 4505 had the `Property_Key` 9978 instead of `NULL`, should its descendants (5066, 6121, and 5068) display `Property_Key` 9978, or 325?

Comment: If the row ID 4505 has Property_Key 9978 instead of NULL, then its descendants would display 325. Thanks

Comment: So, why 325 instead of 2 (`Property_Key` from the actual top parent record)? Is that first one supposed to be ignored for some reason? The natural pattern would assign 2 to all NULLs, not 325.

Comment: FYI - updated my answer to cover what you're asking for from your last comment; include how to use actual highest ancestor's value as default, instead of second-highest ancestor.

Comment: My apologies, I did not read your comment correctly. What you had as the first answer was correct. However, I am sure your updated answer will help someone else in the future. I was supposed to say that the descendants would have Property_Key 9978.

Comment: No problem - I'd figured it out both ways, just figured the answer you *did* want was the answer you *would* want, so only added the other when it looked like it wasn't. As you said, someone may find it useful! Glad you're able to move on to your next step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is running an infinite loop because it always finds more records that can be added. That's because the rows you're adding in the second half of the query (after the UNION ALL) are the exact rows that are in the first half of the query. You won't get an infinite loop if you use the columns from the `@MappingPartOne` table, not `CTE`, in the SELECT list. You won't get what you *want* but you won't get an infinite loop.

If I'm understanding you correctly, when a row's `Property_Key` is NULL, you want to use the same `Property_Key` value as used by the row's parent - in other words, the *nearest ancestor*'s `Property_Key` where that value is not NULL.  For example: if the row with `Functional_Location_Key` = 4505 had `Property_Key` = 9978 instead of NULL, its descendants (`Functional_Location_Key` 5066, 6121, and 5068) would display `Property_Key` = 9978.

We need to make several changes to your query to accomplish this:

- First, as previously noted, the second part of the CTE should output the columns from the `@MappingPartOne` table, not from `CTE`. This, however, gives you multiple copies of your rows.
- To get a single copy of each of your rows, you need to start the CTE differently. You're initially explicitly providing a list of the rows you want to see in the first part of the CTE. However, then, in the second part, you're bringing in the *descendants* of each row from the previous iteration. Since you've included rows in the first part that are the descendants of other rows you've included, you get duplicates as you iterate through the rows.

  Instead, you need to specify just the ultimate parent rows - rows that aren't descendants of any other rows. That means, the rows (in the present case, row) where `Parent_Key` is NULL.
- Now, the next step is to check if a row's `Property_Key` is NULL, and (if so) to use the same value as its parent did. It doesn't matter if the parent's `Property_Key` was also NULL, because then it would be using *its* parent's `Property_Key`. During each iteration through our data, we have the current row (from `@MappingPartOne`) and its parent (from `CTE`). So, instead of simply using the `@MappingPartOne.Property_Key`, we check if that's NULL. If it's not, we use it - if it is, we use `CTE.Property_Key`.

So, this gives us the following query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        m.Functional_Location_Key           
        ,m.Parent_Key
        ,m.Level
        ,m.Property_Key
    FROM #MappingPartOne m
    WHERE m.Parent_Key IS NULL

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        b.Functional_Location_Key           
        ,b.Parent_Key
        ,b.Level
        ,COALESCE(b.Property_Key, t.Property_Key) as Property_Key
    FROM CTE t
    JOIN #MappingPartOne b ON b.Parent_Key = t.Functional_Location_Key
)
SELECT  
    Functional_Location_Key         
    ,Parent_Key
    ,Level
    ,Property_Key
FROM CTE
;
```

You can see this in action at [this SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95af13/4).

(If you haven't used it before, `COALESCE()` works like the `ISNULL()` function. It has two potential advantages: you can provide more than two arguments, in which case it will return the first non-NULL argument, or NULL if all of them are NULL; and, it's part of the ANSI standard, and thus more likely to be portable to other SQL dialects.)

If you change the `WHERE` clause criteria in the first part of the CTE to pick a specific row by `Functional_Location_Key`, then you can pull up any given row and its descendants, ignoring the rest of the hierarchy, in case that's needed.

---

Per your comments, you seem to want to show the `Property_Key` from the highest level ancestor with a parent (not from roe 1393, but from row 1399) as the default for all its descendants with a NULL `Property_Key`.

To do this, we need only need to introduce an additional column to our CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        m.Functional_Location_Key           
        ,m.Parent_Key
        ,m.Level
        ,m.Property_Key
        ,NULL as Top_Property_Key
    FROM MappingPartOne m
    WHERE m.Parent_Key IS NULL

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        b.Functional_Location_Key           
        ,b.Parent_Key
        ,b.Level
        ,COALESCE(b.Property_Key, t.Top_Property_Key) as Property_Key
        ,COALESCE(t.Top_Property_Key, b.Property_Key) as Top_Property_Key
    FROM CTE t
    JOIN MappingPartOne b ON b.Parent_Key = t.Functional_Location_Key
)
SELECT  
    Functional_Location_Key         
    ,Parent_Key
    ,Level
    ,Property_Key
FROM CTE
;
```

The new column is `Top_Property_Key`. Initially, we're looking at the top level parent. You've said we don't want to use that as our default, so we set the value for this one row to NULL. In the second part of the CTE, we want to use the established `Top_Property_Key` as our default if it's not currently NULL, otherwise we want to use the current parent row's `Property_Key`. Once we have a row where `Top_Property_Key` is assigned a non-NULL value, it will retain that value for all its children.

Finally, we change the `COALESCE` for each row's `Property_Key` to use our new column, `t.Top_Property_Key`, instead of `t.Property_Key` (the immediate parent's property key value).

Here's an updated [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95af13/6/2) with the new functionality.

NOTE: If you decide you want to use the very top parent's `Property_Key` as the default for all its children, then set `Top_Property_Key` to `Property_Key` instead of NULL in the first part of the CTE:

```
        ,m.Property_Key as Top_Property_Key
```

Comment: Seeing we both ended up in the same place makes me feel a lot better, hahaha

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanations, seems like i was missing 2 key parts. Starting at the Parent (where Parent_Key is NULL) and the COALESCE